# How do I get select tag value from jQuery(document).on('change', ...)

Tags: jquery

Have one default select box inside a `span`

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/pzphbnxb/18/

```
<span id="all_locations">

<select name="united_kingdom" id="united_kingdom" class="location" >
<option value="blank">Select</option>
<option value="england">England</option>
</select>

</span>
```

1) Click on select box and change value.

2) As result get to display next select box

3) If i click on the next select box, i want to alert (for example) `id` of the clicked select box. But i see alert of the select box above.

Here is jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '.location', function(){

$('#all_locations').append('<select name="loc_in_england" id="loc_in_england" class="location" ><option value="blank">Select</option><option value="london">London</option>');    

alert ( $('.location').find(":selected").val() + ' selected val' );
alert( $(".location").attr('id') + ' select id' );    

}); //$(document).on('change'
```

I mean, i clicked `'.location'`, clicked certain select box, i must get `attr('id')` of clicked class. Why i get `attr('id')` of class of the first select box?

Do i need to use something like `.closest` to get id of clicked select box? If `.closest`, then closest to what?

Comment: You are using same id for every select after first one which causes  confusion to browser as well as user.

Comment: You mean `id="loc_in_england"` it is only in example. Actually it will display only once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `$(this)` instead of `$('.location')`

```
$(document).on('change', '.location', function(){  
   //    alert('test');
   $('#all_locations').append('<select name="loc_in_england" id="loc_in_england" class="location" ><option value="blank">Select</option><option value="london">London</option>');   
   alert ( $(this).find(":selected").val() + ' selected val' );
   alert( $(this).attr('id') + ' select id' ); 
}); //$(document).on('change'
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzphbnxb/21/)

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/pzphbnxb/22/

Try this

```
alert ($(this).find(":selected").val() + ' selected val' );
alert( $(this).attr('id') + ' select id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("change", "#userTask", function(e) {
  const getData = $('option:selected').text();
  const id = $('#userTask').find(":selected").val();
});
```

In this way you get value and text value from selected tag